# How to add extra text in order e-mail in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Hello i want to change the e-mail answer after a successfull order in my Opencart store.

I just want to add more text in the email.

As far as i know i need to go in :

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl
```

and change the code there but when I do so ,nothing changes.

I am so sorry for my bad English.

Comment: just add your text to mail language file, which one OC is loading at time of sending mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to go inside the  .tpl file

Go here:

```
/catalog/language/bulgarian/mail/order.php
```

you will find this line:

```
$_['text_new_greeting']         = "Your text HERE";
```

Chnage the text inside the "" marks.

That is for Opencart 1.x (i am not sure for 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go in the language file `/catalog/language/*/mail/order.php`.
2. At the end of file, paste this `$_['text_new'] = "Your Text";`.
   The model `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` automatically calls language file so you wont have to call it, but you would have to declare the variable in your model. Go through it and see where mail variables are being made. Add your variable over there. `$data['text_new'] = $this->language->get('text_new');`
3. Go to `catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl` and call your the variable $text_new where ever you need.

That's it.